# Mobile site doesn't recognise right dimensions/resolution

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I'm trying to make my site fully responsive, but it doesn't display at all how I expect it to. I'm using media queries in css and the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` tag, but it doesn't help much. Without the `<meta>` tag it does display correctly I suppose, but of course the pixels are quite small on modern smartphones.

While searching for this issue I found a [page about mobile displays](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml), which makes me understand it a little better. If I get it right, this page mentions that phones pass 'false' information about their resolution as to not show websites too small.

This doesn't make it that much easier, however. My Samsung Galaxy S5, for example, has a resolution 1080 × 1920 pixels, and loads the css that is within `@media screen and (max-width:720px) {}` in both portrait and landscape mode. For my site, it's good that it does that in portrait mode, but in landscape mode I really need it to display the regular css.

Long story short, how would I solve this? How do I know what 'false' resolutions phones pass and make sure that whatever I do works correctly for all mobile devices?

**EDIT:** the site does NOT respond at all to `@media screen and (min-width:720px) and (max-width:1920px)` in landscape mode.